# iOS: Save images in App Group for use on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, ios-app-group

**Background:**

In my iPhone app I retrieve images and save them to the documents directory for quicker loading.  I know that to use these images on the Apple Watch, I must share them with an App Group.

So, I create an App Group, updated my provisioning profile, all that jazz.  Now my problem is that I do not know how to save an image to the App Group and read that image within my WatchKit files.

Here is what I have tried for saving the image to the App Group:

```
NSString *container = @"group.com.appName.watchdatasharing";

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];

[defaults setValue:UIImagePNGRepresentation([FileManager readImageFromFileWithName:@"icon1_imgUrl"]) forKey:@"icon1_imgUrl"];
```

- note: my FileManager class returns a UIImage

And to retrieve the image in my WatchKit app, I use this code:

```
NSString *container = @"group.com.fantrac.watchdatasharing";

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];

NSData* imageData = [defaults valueForKey:@"icon1_imgUrl"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

[tableRow.iconImage setImage:image];
```

**Question:**

There is not image showing when I test on the Apple Watch.  What do I need to do differently to save/ retrieve the images between my app and Apple Watch?

Comment: Are you using watchOS 1 or 2? watchOS 2 can't access shared app groups.

Comment: I am using watchOS 2.... thats odd, can you suggest another solution to using images saved in the documents directory of my app on the watch?

Comment: You'll have to use the WatchConnectivity framework and use the `transferFile:metadata:` method on `WCSession` to transfer the file from the phone to the watch and then save the file in the watch's own documents directory.

Comment: That actually sounds easier to use than my other approach, thanks!  One more thing - will I need to set it up to be able to do both ways... Since some watch devices will have OS 1 and some OS 2?

Comment: If you also have a watchOS 1 app then yeah you should keep storing the images in the app group so people with watchOS 1 can access them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use watchOS 2, you can use WatchConnectivity.  I attach a sample code for your reference.

**on iPhone:**

```
// Create a Watch Connectivity session
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.applicationDict = @{@"foo" : @"bar"};

    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }
}

// Transfer file to Apple Watch 
- (IBAction)fileTransferButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // File Transfer
    NSURL *url = 
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"png"]];
    WCSessionFileTransfer *fileTransfer = 
    [[WCSession defaultSession] transferFile:url
                                    metadata:self.applicationDict];
}
```

**on Watch:**

```
// Receive file from iPhone
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveFile:(nonnull WCSessionFile *)file
{
    // recieve file
}
```

ref.
http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/

Comment: This is great, does watchOS 1 work with WatchConnectivity? Everything I've found only talks about the WatchConnectivity framework with watchOS 2

Comment: WatchConnectivity is not available in watchOS 1.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the original question if you want multiple apps access same "sandbox" your option may include AppGroups.

> Use app groups to allow multiple apps access to shared containers and allow additional interprocess communication between apps

[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html) you can find information how to configure App Group on the **Configuring App Groups** section.

Once you have configured AppGroup and add the correct entitlement to your app, you can access a common container with the following code :

```
NSString * kSharedAppGroup = @"group.com.appName.watchdatasharing";

+ (NSURL*)commonStoreUrl {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *modelDestUrl = [[fileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:kSharedAppGroup] URLByAppendingPathComponent: kStoreName];
    return modelDestUrl;
}
```

Usage:

```
NSURL *commonContainer = [Someclass commonStoreUrl];
```

This will be useful if your app need to access a common database, anyway if your scenario is just trivial information from the watch to the iOS App use WCSession. (available only since watchkit 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

For Swift3

It will be-

```
let sharedFolderURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.your.app")! as URL
```